# Waiting to take at least get 10 samples for PhoneStateListener [LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS]

Tags: android, multithreading, wait

Currently I'm writing a Service which has to take the Signal Strength of user's mobile set.

For this matter, I've implemented an inner class for the Service (lets say myPhoneStateListener) which extends the PhoneStateListener, and by overriding onSignalStrengthsChanged method I can successfully read the Signal Strength values ( from getGsmSignalStrength() method ).

Note that the TelephonyManager instance and listener got initialized in Service OnCreate method.

The issue is that I don't like to get the first value I get in onSignalStrengthsChanged body as Signal Strength value.

What I'd like to achieve is to somehow wait on PhoneStateListener and make sure that the listener has generated at least 10 samples and then save the last Signal Strength as the valid value.

Please be noted that currently I'm reading the values in Service onStartCommand method.

For doing that, I've tried to define a local variable (as counter) in Service class, It'll incremented by 1 each time when onSignalStrengthsChanged is called. in other hand in onStartCommand I'll wait and check if the variable reach to 10:

```
        while ( m_nSignalStrength_Count < 10 )
        {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

But as I checked in debugging-mode, the variable doesn't change at all.

Comment: `while(...) sleep();` terrible idea ... just call some method(or code that you have after `while()`) from `onSignalStrengthsChanged`  when it is called tenth time ... do not wait in `onStartCommand` ...

Comment: Selvin, thank you for reply. sounds great. but the problem is that if I don't wait on OnStartCommand, the OnStartCommand method would be executed without getting any value for Signal Strength. for example because the PhoneStateListener never had enough time to get all samples on the OnStartCommand execution time range.

Comment: so you have something like this? https://gist.github.com/SelvinPL/ff4aa21a818e2538abad

Comment: Yea :) it is pretty much like I've in my code. the only difference was that actually Listener got initialized in Service OnCreate. but you know the rest, so you see .. you may need to take 20 samples instead of 10 , but you cannot guaranty if  the Signal Strength data is feedback to Service in time. and by that I actually refer to OnStartCommand method. because this method will call stopSelf() at the end to stop the service. and somehow I need to stick with current logic, I mean the service has to destroyed at the end of OnStartCommand.

Comment: why don't you try to call `stopSelf()` in `dissableGatheringOfSignalData` ?

Comment: Oh that's right :D ... let me check this .. I'll right be back to put my comment here ;)